# After period of idling, computer sometimes becomes inoperable (but still on)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, sleep

I'm running Windows 10 on an Asus UX430UAR.

There are two power-related bugs I've run into on this machine.

1. When I shut the lid with the intent of putting it to sleep, I eventually noticed that it was often overheating when I came back and reopened it. I assumed that meant that it wasn't going to sleep properly. Ever since I noticed that pattern, I changed the settings to hibernate upon lid closing, rather than sleep upon lid closing. It would be great if anyone knew how to fix that, though, because the extra steps of waking from hibernation can be cumbersome.
2. After the computer enters connected standby, for some apparently random period of time (I have not able to reproduce this consistently), then I am unable to wake the computer screen. The screen will be all black (normal, since it was idle after all) but nothing happens, no matter what keys I press. I have tried Ctrl-Alt-Delete, and all other kinds of key combinations. When in this status, the computer is clearly still running, because there are some lights on the side of the model and they remain on. The computer continues to produce some heat. But nothing I can do wakes the screen.

My only solution to (2) has been to press and hold the power button until the computer shuts off, and to press the power button again to boot it again.

It is unclear what causes (2). I have my display set to turn off after 5 minutes of idling. Sometimes if I step away from my computer for less than ten minutes, I find that my computer has entered this unreachable stage when I come back. Other times, it was idling for much longer than that, but upon pressing a random key (usually I press Ctrl or random letters) I was able to wake it up and log back in.

My system is up to date and I install updates when they become available.

Comment: Reset Power properties to Default. Update BIOS, then Power Drivers.  When done, shut down, start up, set Power Properties and test.

Comment: After certain time the computer switches from standby to hibernate. May be something goes wrong in this switch. Check Windows system event log.

Comment: @Robert what should someone be looking for, and in which log(s)?

Comment: I checked that my BIOS is the latest version, and all my drivers seem to be up to date as well. I reset my power properties to default just now so I hope maybe that fixes it.
I can confirm it's not accidentally hibernating, because if it were in hibernate mode I could just press the power button to turn it back on.